# How to check If there is a string match in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array and I want to check If the string "a" is in one of the objects in it or not .

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    name: 'JootiJeans',
    url: require('./assets/products/shirt.png'),
  },
  {
    name: 'Asics',
    url: require('./assets/products/shoes.png'),
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeanswest',
    url: require('./assets/products/coat.png'),
  },
];
```

I try to check If string "a" is there in the name property of myArray :

```js
const filtered = offerItems.findIndex((any) => any.name.includes(val));
if (filtered) {
  console.log('There is a an object');
} else {
  console.log('No object with string a');
}
```

It doesn't work properly .

How can I check If there is an object with name property which includes string "a" so it will return false or true ?

Comment: findIndex returns -1, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
const val = "a"

const myArray = [
  {
    name: 'JootiJeans',
    url: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Asics',
    url: ''
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeanswest',
    url: ''
  },
];

const filtered = myArray.some((any) => any.name.toLowerCase().includes(val));
if (filtered) {
  console.log('There is a an object');
} else {
  console.log('No object with string a');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  {
    name: 'JootiJeans'
  },
  {
    name: 'Asics'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jeanswest'
  }
];
const regex = /a/gm; // for "A" and "a", add the "i" flag (/a/gmi)
let result = arrayOfObjects.every((obj) => regex.exec(obj.name) != null);
console.log(result);
```